# native javascript to jQuery equivalent simple code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find find out whats the jQuery equivalent of

```
style.display.indexOf('none') > -1)
```

I tried

```
if(jQuery('#container').css(display).index(none) > -1)
```

But i am not sure if its right, can anyone give me a hand

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? And why you have `none` without quotes in the second string?

Comment: 8am no sleep T_T just learning how to code

Comment: Do you want to get '#container' index?

Comment: Don't code with no sleep. Also have a look at how `.css` works: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1.

Comment: I am trying to code this `     if (document.getElementById('_amd').style.display.indexOf('none') > -1) _ab = true;` to jQuery

Comment: @FelixKling You are right, even coding drunk gives you better results.

Comment: Note:  The CSS `display` property values are mutually exclusive; there can only be one value, as far as valid CSS and conforming browsers are concerned. If it *contains* `'none'`, it *is* `'none'`.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: `if ($('#_amd:hidden').length) _ab = true;`

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: `.length` says how many elements the query found.  If it is truthy (ie: nonzero), then there is at least one `#_amd:hidden` (that is, one `#_amd` that is in the tree, but is not visible).

Comment: @CHao does -1 means hidden and 1 means visible?

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: No.  My example checks the number of elements `$('#_amd:hidden')` refers to (ie: how many elements *both* have an ID of `_amd`, *and* are hidden).  If it's 0, there aren't any (meaning either there's no element with the ID `_amd`, or it's not hidden).  If it's 1, then `#_amd` is hidden.

Comment: @JoseDavidGarciaLlanos: You have to use `-1` with `.indexOf` because of how that function works; it returns -1 if what you're looking for isn't found.  As i was saying earlier, though, searching the string is entirely unnecessary.  You'll never have a case in a valid document where `display` *contains* `'none'` without it *being* `'none'`.

Comment: ah, thanks man i got it :) now i can sleep properly =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if(jQuery('#container').is(':hidden')) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that objective is to determine if the display property is set to `none`:

```
jQuery('#container').css("display") === "none"
                           ^^^ Needs to be a string
                                    ^^^ Should be an equality operator
```

Comment: what does the -1 mean? and which are the other values? 1, 0 ?what do they represent

Comment: The number is the position of the first character in the string that matches. If it is -1 there was no match.

Answer (score 1):

You are not enclosing the string in `''`

```
if(jQuery('#container').css('display').index('none') > -1)
```

but is you are looking for whether the element is displayed then use the [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector

```
if(jQuery('#container').is(':visible'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :visible selector in your case it will be something like this:

```
$('#container:visible')
```

which return true or false.